# Connect multiple device with bluetooth in blufi_plugin flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am connecting multiple devices via Bluetooth, but only one device is connected and the other devices are not connected. If you have any solution.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < bluetoothDevicesList.length ; i++) {
                           
 await BlufiPlugin.instance.connectPeripheral(
                                    peripheralAddress:
                                        bluetoothDevicesList[i].address

                                 );
                               
                          }
```